# coloring barplot using a continuous variable - factor not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
library(poliscidata)

world_red <- world %>% group_by(dem_level4) %>% summarize(number_of_countries = n(), oil=sum(oil, na.rm = TRUE))

colors <- c("green", "blue", "orange", "red")
p1 <- ggplot(data = world_red) + 
        aes(x = reorder(dem_level4, -oil) , y = oil, 
            fill = factor(number_of_countries) ) +
        geom_col() + 
        scale_fill_manual(values = colors)
```

The variable "world" is part of the loaded package.

There is no error message in this code, but the legend appears as "factor(number_of_countries"), but, of course, it should only be "number_of_countries". How can I achieve this?

Just writing

```
fill = number_of_countries)  +
```

without calling factor () results in the error message "Continuous value supplied to discrete scale"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `name` argument into `scale_fill_manual`:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = world_red) + 
  aes(x = reorder(dem_level4, -oil) , y = oil, 
      fill = factor(number_of_countries) ) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "number_of_countries", values = colors)
```

Or you can add a `labs` line, then give a new name to `fill`. You can also update the x and y axis labels here too (which I did below).

```
library(tidyverse)

p1 <- ggplot(data = world_red) + 
  aes(x = reorder(dem_level4, -oil) , y = oil, 
      fill = factor(number_of_countries) ) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  labs(fill='number_of_countries',
       y = "Oil", 
       x = "dem_level4")
```

**Output**

[image]